# Storing in a file with or without quiet option in "openssl s_client"

Tags: openssl

I was playing an online capture the flag game where I was doing `openssl` to a server which was returning a private key to `ssh` into another server.

This is the command I ran : `openssl s_client -connect {server} > ae.pub`

I was writing the key in the file `ae.pub` but this didn't work, as in when I tried to ssh into the required server I got incorrect key.

but when I added `-quiet` option I was able to `ssh` into the server correcttly.

like this : `openssl s_client -connect {server} -quiet > ae.pub`

What is `-quiet` option doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (`man s_client`):

> ```
>    -quiet
>        inhibit printing of session and certificate information.  This
>        implicitly turns on -ign_eof as well.
> ```

The `openssl` command is a debugging tool that's grown to be a key management tool. Many of its subcommands print debugging information, sometimes to standard error, sometimes to standard output. For `s_client`, the option `-quiet` happens to suppress some debugging information that's otherwise printed to standard output.

Without `-quiet`, the debugging information was mixed with the expected content in the output file.

If you aren't debugging a TLS server, `openssl s_client` isn't a particularly useful command. A good tool for setting up all kinds of network connections is [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

```
socat - OPENSSL:server.example.com:4433 </dev/null >ae.pub
```